# SSH Key authorization for user

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-server

Scenario : 
There are multiple users who need SSH into a server. What I'm following is

1. Create user1 , user2 in the server (Ubuntu 14.04 Server) running in AWS EC2.
2. Add each user public key (`id_rsa.pub`) into server `/home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys` file

Problem is I only can SSH to `ubuntu` (Default user)  with the private key of the user. But I can not SSH into `user1` user.

Sample

```
[root@rubi-pc Downloads]# ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ruwan@DummyIP -v
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to DummyIP [DummyIP] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to DummyIP:22 as 'ruwan'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:0kqNAt37ILO4cCP8ioiLN9j9x9badLOGL+etIvSYzfs
debug1: Host 'DummyIP' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Please do let me know if any details requeired .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Occurred because of .ssh/authorized_keys not chowned to $USER and groups.
also chmod `-rw-rw-r-- ( 664 )` .

Answer (score 1):

You have got the filename wrong. It is not

```
/home/$USER/.ssh/authorize_key
```

but

```
/home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: This is my mistake in the post, fixed the file name in the post.

Comment: Still wrong. What are the permissions on that file?

Comment: Sorry fixed file name, file permission `700` , tried `777` as well , same `Permission denied (publickey)`. error

Comment: Run `ls -ld ~$USER ~$USER/.ssh ~$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys` and update the question with the information.

Comment: that leads to check group and file permission, fixed with thanks.